# Look up for a value in a csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv, lookup

I need to look up a value in a csv file given a criteria in a function. When I run my program I get all the values but not the one associated with my entry. Any help will be appreciated.

The date looks something like this:

```
rose,7.95
lily,3.95
begonia,5.95
```

The function I created is:

```
def problem3_8(csv_pricefile, flower):
    import csv    

    archivo = open(csv_pricefile)

    for row in csv.reader(archivo):
        if flower in row[0]:
            print(row[1])

    archivo.close()
```

When I ran the program using the next line:

```
problem3_7("flowers.csv","rose")
```

I get all the value in the file, like this:

```
7.95
3.95
5.95
```

But the answer should be just the value associated with the second entry.

```
7.95
```

Thanks

Comment: Is a csv file with two rows. The 1st row has the name of the flowers and the second one the prices. I need to look up the price of a flower given the 2nd argument in the function which is the flower name. "def problem3_8(csv_pricefile, flower)"

Comment: On re-visiting your question, your code should work. I think you might be printing the content from somewhere else. Even though better way would have been `flower == row[0]` to check for exact match. But based on your sample data, it should print just one value

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code given and had the correct output of 7.95.

Is it possible you called the wrong function? In your question you referred to the function problem3_7 instead of the function problem3_8

Comment: Hi Bryce, yes I meant problem3_7  in both instances.That's why it wast working :( I got so confuse trying different things, that I didn't even realize of my mistake! Thanks for your help :) P.S. I am new in programming, LOL!